# Case study : Blockchain as a service

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, ether, ethereum-wallet-dapp, blockchain-as-a-service

I have a web application which has DynamoDB as the database. I want to store some **SCORE** in a DynamoDB table.

How can I restrict this **SCORE** to only some set of people in my web application can modify by using blockchain?

Users in my application enters some items, With some logic in application we are giving a **SCORE**. So whenever the user modifies the items the **SCORE** is changing. By using blockchain can i include **SCORE** in blockchain?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please provide more information about the restrictions? You only want to allow blockchain users, e.g. those who have MetaMask installed, to be counted towards your score?

Comment: Hello @PaulRBerg 
Users in my application enters some items, With some logic in application we are giving a **SCORE**. So whenever the user modifies the items the **SCORE** is changing. By using blockchain can i include **SCORE** in blockchain?

Comment: Hi @PaulRBerg, Is there any way that **SCORE** is modified by users of application and that should be approved by the **blockchain** users??
My need is **SCORE** should be there in blockchain..